# Link to another file

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm generating a word document by using open-xml.

There i show names of image files 
i.e. 
c:\config\1.jpg
c:\config\2.jpg

On-click on those names (cntl+click) those file should be opened. But it doesnt go to the file rather than an anchor to top of the word doc.

I used hyperlink as below

```
Paragraph paraSummary = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
Run runSummary = paraSummary.AppendChild(new Run());
runSummary.AppendChild(new Break());
Hyperlink hl = new Hyperlink(new Run(new Text(item.ToString())))
{
 DocLocation = rootPath1 + "\\" + item.ToString()
};
runSummary.AppendChild(hl);

mainPart.Document.Append(body);
mainPart.Document.Save();
```

and the xml of generated file is :

```
-<w:hyperlink w:docLocation="c:\\config\\1.jpg">-<w:r><w:t>1.jpg</w:t></w:r></w:hyperlink>
```

is there any other solution other than 'Hyperlinks' or anything that i have missed in above code.

Comment: Try manually creating a word file and adding an hyperlink to an Image there, if that works, you can view the xml for that and then try replicating the same in your code. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Open XML spec. 
http://officeopenxml.com/WPhyperlink.php
`docLocation` is for external links.

For All types of hyperlinks we have to create a relationship.
for example

In your case TargetMode can't be external

In Open XML SDK you can implement this as below code sample

```
Hyperlink hl =
new Hyperlink(new Run(new Text("Link1")))
{
    Id = "L1"
};

runSummary.AppendChild(hl);

mainPart.Document.Append(body);
mainPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new Uri("file:\\C:\\config\\image.jpg"), false, "L1");
```

in AddHyperlinkRelationship method false means that this is not external link (which  is for internal link)